# Help me find (ok, calculate/approx/uncover) the p-value in the following tables

Tags: statistical-significance, multiple-regression, p-value, f-statistic

For a meta-analysis I am looking for the p-values in these tables derived from reports dating back to 1980...

[image]

[image]

I am, by now, pretty sure I can't but maybe there is someone smarter than me here... If you want to check out the original documents, find them here:

https://www.ncjrs.gov/pdffiles1/Digitization/71109NCJRS.pdf
https://www.ncjrs.gov/pdffiles1/Digitization/47077NCJRS.pdf

The tables are in the appendix.

Comment: Doesn't look like the p-values are outright stated but since you have the number of observations (N at bottom), degrees of freedom, and the test-statistic values you could get close approximations of the p-values the original analysts found

Comment: @jros how would you go about this? We have N observations but not the N of how often the individual dummy variables are present...

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.

Comment: @kjetil This isn't self-study.  It's a meta-analysis, as stated in the initial sentence.  The document itself is over 40 years old (and very badly written), making it unlikely as a source for any form of self-study.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen it is no self-study indeed and no homework. Thanks Whuber for pointing that out... What I have tried is see if there is any way to compute a p value, which I have not found. I decided yesterday the whole exercise might be a karikature: the sign of the dummy variables is dependent on the chosen reference group, which is arbitrary. What I am thinking now is taking the F statistic for the whole model and sample size as df-numerator and no. of dummies as df-denumerator and calculating p-value this way...